# My laptop no longer connects to my college wifi network

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my college network. After some days of using the internet continuously, it doesn't connect anymore. When I put my friends MAC address on my laptop, it works fine, but not for my mac address. My friend also faces the same issue. What's the problem?

Comment: Same friend or different friend? "Same issue" with your MAC address or a different MAC address or the MAC address that works with your laptop? Is there any reason or possibility your MAC address could have been blacklisted?

Comment: i put different friend's mac address it connects well . they told that they will never black list any of the students mac address.In my colleage they have three wifi but my wifi is not connecting to that particular one that i used constantly.i think there is some issue with ubuntu and my colleage's wifi

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Why do you think that this issue is related to Ubuntu? Do you have the same issue connecting to other wireless access points?

Comment: while using ubuntu me and my friend has this issue ,while my others friends using windows has no issues with it

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you should ask your college IT team to whitelist your laptop's media access control (MAC) address. They've enabled MAC filtering of the college WiFi routers. Once they add your machine's MAC address to the whitelist for their WiFi  routers though their admin console, this will resolve your issue.

Comment: i already registered with my colleage wifi. i have been using it for 1 year in windows . now i installed ubuntu this problem occurs. my friend also have the same issue